# AutoMapper 4 mapping Error

Tags: c#, serialization, orm, automapper, poco

I have two classes. One is a class named "ImportedContact" that maps to records in a csv file. For each row in the file there is an instace of this class. We use LINQtoCSV library to retrieve the values into this class. The second is a class named "Contact" used with Telerik's DataAccess ORM library. So our process is to read the csv file with LINQtoCSV filling the ImportedContact class instances and mapping them each into a Contact class instance where we add them to the Database Context and update our database. When we map between these classes I get an exception that doesn't make sense to me.

Here is the ImportedContact class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using LINQtoCSV;

namespace SharePointDirectory.Jobs
{
    public class ImportedContact
    {
        [CsvColumn(Name = "Location Name", FieldIndex = 4)]
        public string BranchId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "Work Wireless", FieldIndex = 7)]
        public string CellNumber
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "Home Department Name", FieldIndex = 3)]
        public string Dept
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "Extension", FieldIndex = 9)]
        public string Ext
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "First Name", FieldIndex = 2)]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "Last Name", FieldIndex = 1)]
        public string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "Shift -- Value", FieldIndex = 5)]
        public string Shift
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "Job Title", FieldIndex = 8)]
        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [CsvColumn(Name = "Work Phone", FieldIndex = 6)]
        public string WorkNumber
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Contact class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace SharePointDirectory.Data  
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Contact : ISerializable
    {
        public Contact()
        {
        }

        protected Contact(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.Id = info.GetInt64("Id");
            this.EmployeeId = (int?)info.GetValue("EmployeeId", typeof(int?));
            this.FirstName = info.GetString("FirstName");
            this.LastName = info.GetString("LastName");
            this.Title = info.GetString("Title");
            this.Ext = info.GetString("Ext");
            this.Dept = info.GetString("Dept");
            this.DeptId = info.GetString("DeptId");
            this.CellNumber = info.GetString("CellNumber");
            this.PhotoPath = info.GetString("PhotoPath");
            this.Active = info.GetBoolean("Active");
            this.Office = info.GetBoolean("Office");
            this.Shift = info.GetString("Shift");
            this.BranchId = info.GetString("BranchId");
            this.WorkNumber = info.GetString("WorkNumber");
        }

        public bool Active
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string BranchId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string CellNumber
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Dept
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string DeptId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int? EmployeeId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Ext
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public long Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool Office
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string PhotoPath
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Shift
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string WorkNumber
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("Id", this.Id, typeof(long));
            info.AddValue("EmployeeId", this.EmployeeId, typeof(int?));
            info.AddValue("FirstName", this.FirstName, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("LastName", this.LastName, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("Title", this.Title, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("Ext", this.Ext, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("Dept", this.Dept, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("DeptId", this.DeptId, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("CellNumber", this.CellNumber, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("PhotoPath", this.PhotoPath, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("Active", this.Active, typeof(bool));
            info.AddValue("Office", this.Office, typeof(bool));
            info.AddValue("Shift", this.Shift, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("BranchId", this.BranchId, typeof(string));
            info.AddValue("WorkNumber", this.WorkNumber, typeof(string));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how we setup the mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(configuration => configuration.CreateMap<ImportedContact, Contact>());
```

Here is how we perform the actual map at runtime:

```
var contact = Mapper.Map<Contact>(importedContact);
```

When we perform the map this is the exception message we are seeing:

```
{
    "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

    Mapping types:
    ImportedContact -> SerializationInfo
    SharePointDirectory.Jobs.ImportedContact -> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo

    Destination path:
    Contact

    Source value:
    SharePointDirectory.Jobs.ImportedContact"
}   

System.Exception {AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException}
```

I don't understand why it's trying to perform a map on those two types listed there. SerializationInfo is a constructor argument on one of the constructors, but there is a parameterless constructer also that I feel it should be paying attention to, not the other way around. Also this same code seemed to work fine in AutoMapper version 3.3.

I've been going over the AutoMapper documentation to see if I can find anything. The closest thing so far is it mentioning these two things.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Construction

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration

Specifically the statement about Configuration prefixes:

```
By default AutoMapper recognizes the prefix "Get"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in that `AutoMapper` decided to use the constructor with parameters instead of the default constructor.

My workaround was to instantiate the destination object myself and make `AutoMapper` fill out the properties:

```
var contact = new Contact();
Mapper.Map(importedContact, contact);
```

Comment: My example shows two specific types causing an issue. But actually the code is written with Generics <Ts, Td>. So we have always depended on Automapper performing the object instantiation of type Td. We would have to refactor the code to do our own Activator.CreateInstance to call it that way. I was kind of hoping there was something that could be expressed in the mapping configuration rather than being only able to call specific Map methods in the API.

Comment: I understand. I think the behavior changed in a newer version of AutoMapper, because I got the error after upgrading through NuGet. I don't know if there is a configuration for it, sorry. I will let my answer stay since it may prove useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about never versions of auto mapper but I think, you still need to specify destination mapping class, otherwise it does not know where to map.

```
var contact = Mapper.Map<ImportedContact, Contact>(importedContact);
```

Comment: Automapper doesn't need both types declared. It can determine the source type implied through argument. The destination type is given via generic declaration. Automapper supports this syntax/api in version 3.